# How to deep populate with self-referential model Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to populate across multiple levels using the following fields firstly from an Article model:

```
 comments: [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                 ref: "Comment"
            
            }
        ]
```

and then from the Comment model:

```
  replies : [ {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
     }]
```

I have referred to the Mongoose docs on populating across multiple levels and numerous other resources to create my query:

```
    const getArticle = async (req, res) => {
  const slug = { slug: req.params.slug};
  const page = "Article";
   let article = await Article.findOne(slug)
    .populate({
      path: "comments",
      model: "Comment",
      options: {
        sort: { date: -1}
      },
      populate:{
        path: "replies",
        model: "Comment",
        options: {
          sort: { date: -1}
        }
      }
    })

  console.log("articlePop:", article);
  res.render("show", { page, article });
};
```

When I check the documents in Mongosh everything appears as it should with the correct ref _ids in place, however the query does not populate the replies field:

```
     {
  _id: new ObjectId("630f83777b023e0af292dd4a"),
  username: 'noffler',
  date: '31/08/2022, 16:51:19',
  title: 'the napoleonic wars',
  article: 'the return of Napoleon',
  likes: 0,
  dislikes: 0,
  comments: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("630f83917b023e0af292dd50"),
      username: 'noffler',
      date: '31/08/2022, 16:51:45',
      comment: 'some say money is bad for the soul',
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0,
      replies: [Array],
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  slug: 'the-napoleonic-wars',
  __v: 0
}
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. Kind Regards.

Comment: Are you sure it's not populated? The data you're showing is truncated and doesn't show the actual contents of `comment.replies`.

Comment: Dankjewel Robert! It was indeed truncated. I've not come across this before.

Comment: Graag gedaan ;) `console.log()` uses [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors) under the hood, which by default has a depth of 2; objects which require deeper recursion than that will be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

***maybe***
1 - you missed add `exec` function at the end

```js
let article = await Article.findOne(slug)
  .populate({
    path: "comments",
    model: "Comment",
    options: {
      sort: { date: -1}
    },
    populate:{
      path: "replies",
      model: "Comment",
      options: {
        sort: { date: -1}
      }
    }
  }).exec(function(err, docs) {});
```

or 2 - you should add [] around replies object

```js
   let article = await Article.findOne(slug)
    .populate({
      path: "comments",
      model: "Comment",
      options: {
        sort: { date: -1}
      },
      populate:[{
        path: "replies",
        model: "Comment",
        options: {
          sort: { date: -1}
        }
      }]
    })
```

I hope it will be help you

Comment: When using promises/await, there's no need to use `.exec()`.